# setContentView(R.layout.Main); Main cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-widget, javadoc

This is a simple program for beginning (simple for you, not for me) eclipse. I want to change a text by clicking on a button, but it's not working.

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.androidcourse;  

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.TextView;  
import android.R.layout;  

public class MainActivity extends Activity {  

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.Main);  


Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_action); 
final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_caption);  
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

@Override  
public void onClick(View v) {
text.setText("New bingo...");  
}  
});  
}  
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First just build your project. If it will not work, then delete from imports android.R.layout and use layout from your package.

Comment: To elaborate for posterity: "import android.R.layout" should be replaced with "import your.package.here.R"

Answer (score 4):

```
setContentView(R.layout.Main);
```

DO you have layout named Main ? as far as I know Capital letter do not mix well with layout names. If you use it you will get some error like this

> File-based resource names must start with a lowercase letter.

Please check and rename your layout file .

Comment: thanks sunny i changed that but now eclipse say "The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})" here my coding http://up.vatandownload.com/images2/xzyu5gzvvfnd7dwya1te.png

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.Main); is it looking for a xml called main, located in the layout folder?

Answer (score 4):

First check the name of your layout XML (`YourProject/res/layout/your_main.xml` of your project folder).

replace:

```
setContentView(R.layout.**Main**);
```

with:

```
setContentView(R.layout.**your_main**);   // 'your_main' Your layout xml file name.
```

Mine was **activity_main**.xml, which I replaced with "**main**".

I am just a beginner. I may be wrong but this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

just type:
import android.R.layout;
This solved my problem hope it solves your problem too.

Answer (score -1):

Remove all imports and regenerate, by alt+ Enter on every class that require import , this worked for me.

Comment: So in Android IDE /Gradle Plugin the R is file which is generated by the Internal Parser. In your layout folder please check if you have the Main.layout file available.

Comment: Please add your answer to make sense, it looks like there is something missing after the '+'

Comment: it is alt+enter to generate import whenever required.